# How to assert JSON with multiple properties in JSON response

Tags: request, cypress, mocha.js, end-to-end

My server returns a JSON response in Postman which has the following form:

```json
     {
       "accountType": "CHECKING",
       "message": "Your account is overdrawn",
       "withdrawalCode": 'SZWW-2000-11-CD'
    }
```

I am sending a request using Cypress like so and trying to assert all fields. Here is my attempt

```js
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://users/bank-account/withdrawal', 
        body: {     
          name: "paul.king@asher-bank.com",
          password: "test123"
        },
        failOnStatusCode:false
     }).its('body')
       .should('have.property', 'accountType', 'Checking')
       .should('have.property', 'message','User with withdrawal ref: \'CCR-001-009-GG\' is overdrawn')
       .should('have.property', 'withdrawalCode','SZWW-2000-11-CD')
    })
```

Only the first property assertion is allowed of the 3 properties. The other 2 are not allowed. How can I assert multiple properties.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation [.should() - Yields](https://docs-vercel.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Yields)

> In most cases, `.should()` yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.
>
> ```js
> cy.get('nav') // yields <nav>
>  .should('be.visible') // yields <nav>
> ```
>
> However, some chainers change the subject. In the example below, the second `.should()` yields the string `sans-serif` because the chainer `have.css, 'font-family'` ***changes the subject.***
>
> ```js
> cy.get('nav') // yields <nav>
>   .should('be.visible') // yields <nav>
>   .should('have.css', 'font-family') // yields 'sans-serif'
>   .and('match', /serif/) // yields 'sans-serif'
> ```

One way to solve, use a callback function:

```js
.should($body => {
  expect($body.prop('accountType').to.eq('Checking')
  expect($body.prop('message').to.eq('User with withdrawal ref: \'CCR-001-009-GG\' is overdrawn')
  expect($body.prop('withdrawalCode').to.eq('SZWW-2000-11-CD')
})
```

or individually

```js
.should($body => { expect($body.prop('accountType').to.eq('Checking') })
.and($body => { expect($body.prop('message').to.eq('User with withdrawal ref: \'CCR-001-009-GG\' is overdrawn') })
.and($body => { expect($body.prop('withdrawalCode').to.eq('SZWW-2000-11-CD') })
```

Comment: Thanks but I had already posted how I got it to work

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it worked:

```js
          .then(  (response) => {
            // response.body is automatically serialized into JSON
           expect(response.body).to.have.property('accountType', 'Checking') 
           expect(response.body).to.have.property('withdrawal', 'Your account is overdrawn ref: \'CDX-SW009-00F\'') // true
           expect(response.body).to.have.property('withdrawalCode', 'SDW-009-009-001') // true
         }
```